# Suggestions on Word Parsing

Tags: python, regex, parsing, date

I have a set of folders and files that have arbitrary names. My end goal is to parse through the folders and files and create a nicely sorted and named set of folders. These titles sometimes have spaces as delimiters and sometimes have periods (I haven't found any examples with anything other than those as delimiters). I want to display these filenames without delimiters and with only the real words (specific the title of the file and a date if the date is relevant). I'm not worrying about the dates for now, I have a lookup table to figure out the dates based on the correctly spelled title.

**Examples of titles**:

1. `a.bad.title.asdf.1975` (where asdf is the author or website the file was scraped from).

**The title should read:** `A Bad Title (1975)`

2. `another bad title asdf.com 1975`

**Should read:** `Another Bad Title (1975)`

3. `a really.bad title[1975]`

**Should read:** `A Really Bad Title (1975)`

**What I've tried:**

**Possible Solution:** Parse through the words using the delimiters to pull out each separate word and do a word search with a large dictionary I have to figure out if the given element of the array is a word.

**Problem 1:** `A.bad.title.1975` becomes `('a', 'bad', 'title', '1975')` and I can work with it without a problem. However, a really.bad title[1975] becomes `('a', 'really', 'bad', 'title[1975]')` and can't be dealt with.

**Problem 2:** Some of the titles are numbers or parts of numbers like `'71` or `2012` or `2001: A Space Odyssey`, so I can't just parse through what real words are.

**EDIT (Examples of problem 2):**

Filename 1: `'72.2014.asdf.txt`

Filename 2: `2012 [2009].txt`

Filename 3: `2001: a.space.odyssey[1968].txt`

**END OF EDIT**

In other words, my problem is that I want to be able to remove a given date or random numbers, but I want to keep the date if it pertains to the title (as some titles are dates or years) and some of the words in the title are attached (without spaces) to the year in the title and can't be parsed out.

My last idea is possibly giving scores to each possible title based on how many words they have in common, but that still leaves the "year as a title" problem unsolved.

If anyone has any suggestions that might help me think about this problem, please let me know!

Comment: @Pradheep The code isn't having any issues, it's the logic behind the code that I am having problems with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick n' Dirty:

```
import re

for title in [
        "a.bad.title.asdf.1975",
        "another bad title asdf.com 1975",
        "a really.bad title[1975]"]:
   print(" ".join(map(str.title, re.findall(r"\w+", title))))
```

#### Output

```
A Bad Title Asdf 1975
Another Bad Title Asdf Com 1975
A Really Bad Title 1975
```

In this form, it should be easy to compare against known titles.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will achieve most of the desired results. It could easily be rewritten to use regex but I felt in this format it would be easier to tweak further if you find other cases in your folder structure which do not convert as needed.

```
ltest = ["a.bad.title.asdf.1975", "another bad title asdf.com 1975", "a really.bad title[1975]"]

lsub = [(".", " "), ("_", " "), ("[", " "), ("(", " "), ("]", " "), (")", " ")]

for test in ltest:
    # Remove all unwanted characters

    for before, after in lsub:
        test = test.replace(before, after)

    # Split into a list of non-empty words

    ltest = test.split(" ")
    ltest = [test for test in ltest if len(test)]

    # Join them back together with a single space and wrap the last word in parenthesis

    test = " ".join(ltest[:-1]) + " (%s)" % ltest[-1]
    output = test.title().strip()

    print "'%s'" % output
```

This gives the following output:

```
'A Bad Title Asdf (1975)'
'Another Bad Title Asdf Com (1975)'
'A Really Bad Title (1975)'
```

I think you need to give some examples regarding your "Problem 2"

**Update**

`lsub` could be extended to deal with specific websites, but knowing if a word is an author would be a challenge.

e.g.

```
lsub = [("asdf.com", " "), (".", " "), ("_", " "), ("[", " "), ("(", " "), ("]", " "), (")", " ")]
```

Which would fix the second test:

```
'Another Bad Title (1975)'
```

Comment: He wants to get rid of the "asdf" and "asdf.com", I assume from the question. This is good to get some sort of standard in terms of formatting though.

Comment: Agreed. I cannot see a generic solution to removing those, but if they have been scraped from a small number of sites then it would be easy to add these to the `lsub` list explicitly.

Comment: Thanks guys, I didn't think of substituting the parentheses and square brackets for spaces! That seems so simple, but actually is great! Also, there are more than just `asdf`. Sometimes, just tons of random text and stuff that doesn't relate to the title at all, but I think this will help weed it out!

Comment: I added 3 examples of problem 2, also, Martin! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do some pre-processing to try to get rid of the extra information. If the unwanted parts are very limited in number, look at the update of Martin's answer, and name them.

If there's too many of them, find out what formatting types are common in the unwanted parts of titles. You need to look at their formats and try to avoid these parts by recognizing them first.

For example, `(?:(?<=\s|^)([^.]*?)(?:\s|$))` will capture only words divided by spaces that don't contain dots, avoiding site names. See: https://regex101.com/r/rK9zJ2/3 . `another bad title asdf.com 1975` will turn into `another bad title 1975` and easy to process. Now, this isn't the solution to your problem as it doesn't process `another.bad.title.1934`, but you get the idea - know what types of information you want to avoid.

You may find out that site names are what need to be removed. `(?<=\s|^|\.)(?:\w*?\.(?:com|de|org|se)|(\w*?))(?=\s|$|\.)` is a regex I made that also processes `really.bad.titles`, but doesn't capture sites. (.com, .de, .org, .se) as specified. See [**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/rK9zJ2/4). Regex is not the easiest way to do it though (though maybe the shortest code-length-wise).

`a.really.bad.title.by.asfd.1995` may be another thing, add `by someone` or `by someone.com` to the things you don't want to capture: `(?<=\s|^|\.)(?:\w*?\.(?:com|de|org|se)|by(?:\s|.)\w*?(?:\.(?:com|de|org|se))?|(\w*?))(?=\s|$|\.)`, as seen https://regex101.com/r/rK9zJ2/5. Now, when you do things like these with regexes, they tend to get long and difficult to read. Does the trick though. All in all, decide what you want to not capture and figure out how to write the formats, either with regexes or something else. There's no way around specifying what you want to avoid.

Comment: This works amazingly! I still can't figure out how to add the URLs that have www.something.com in a regex though. Wouldn't it just be `(?:www.)` ? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I found a really good regex that does the trick while following these rules:

1. No punctuation except apostrophes and $, #, and !
2. Underscores should be spaces.

Here it is:

```
new_title = re.sub(ur"[^\$#! | ^\w\d'\s]+",' ',title).replace('_', ' ')
```